# Statements vs Expressions in Haskell, Ocaml, Javascript

Tags: haskell, f#, ocaml

In Haskell, afaik, there are no statements, just expressions. That is, unlike in an imperative language like Javascript, you cannot simply execute code line after line, i.e.

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = a + b
print(c)
```

Instead, everything is an expression and nothing can simply modify state and return nothing (i.e. a statement). On top of that, everything would be wrapped in a function such that, in order to mimic such an action as above, you'd use the monadic `do` syntax and thereby hide the underlying nested functions.

Is this the same in OCAML/F# or can you just have imperative statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a complicated topic.  Technically, in ML-style languages, everything is an expression.  However, there is some syntactic sugar to make it read more like statements.  For example, the sample you gave in F# would be:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = a + b
printfn "%d" c
```

However, the compiler silently turns those "statements" into the following expression for you:

```
let a = 1 in
    let b = 2 in
        let c = a + b in
            printfn "%d" c
```

Now, the last line here is going to do IO, and unlike in Haskell, it won't change the type of the expression to `IO`.  The type of the expression here is `unit`.  `unit` is the F# way of expressing "this function doesn't really have result" in the type system.  Of course, if the function doesn't have a result, in a purely functional language it would be pointless to call it.  The only reason to call it would be for some side-effect, and since Haskell doesn't allow side-effects, they use the `IO` monad to encode the fact the function has an IO producing side-effect into the type system.

F# and other ML-based languages do allow side-effects like IO, so they have the `unit` type to represent functions that only do side-effects, like printing.  When designing your application, you will generally want to avoid having `unit`-returning functions except for things like logging or printing.  If you feel so inclined, you can even use F#'s moand-ish feature, Computation Expressions, to encapsulate your side-effects for you.

Comment: I think it's more useful to think of IO values in Haskell as reified imperative effects than a type-level tag. That explains type signatures like `Int -> IO (IO Int)` or `IO a -> IO (Maybe a)` far better.  But this doesn't invalidate anything in your response, which is great.

Comment: In Haskell, we occasionally use functions producing values of the unit type `()` (whose sole constructor is also called `()`) to force lazy things. Most notably, the `NFData` class in `Control.DeepSeq` has the method `rnf :: a -> ()`, which reduces its argument to normal form before producing `()`. An example: to force all elements of a list `xs` to weak head normal form, you can use `rnf (map (\ !_ -> ()) xs)`.

Answer (score 4):

Not to be picky, but there's no language OCaml/F# :-)

To answer for OCaml: OCaml is not a pure functional language. It supports side effects directly through mutability, I/O, and exceptions. In many cases it treats such constructs as expressions with the value `()`, the single value of type `unit`.

Expressions of type `unit` can appear in a sequence separated by `;`:

```ml
let s = ref 0 in
while !s < 10 do
    Printf.printf "%d\n" !s;  (* This has type unit *)
    incr s                    (* This has type unit *)
done                          (* The while as a whole has type unit *)
```

**Update**

More specifically, `;` ignores the value of the first expression and returns the value of the second expression. The first expression should have type `unit` but this isn't absolutely required.

```ml
# print_endline "hello"; 44 ;;
hello
- : int = 44
# 43 ; 44 ;;
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
- : int = 44
```

The `;` operator is right associative, so you can write a `;`-separated sequence of expressions without extra parentheses. It has the value of the last (rightmost) expression.

Comment: So OCAML has a sequencing operator `;` which only returns the results of the second expression?

Comment: The `;` operator ignores the value of the first expression and returns the value of the second expression. The second expression doesn't have to have type `unit`. If the first expression doesn't have type `unit` there is a warning from the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question we need to define what is an expression and what is a statement.

## Distinction between expressions and statements

In layman terms, an expression is something that evaluates (reduces) to a value. It is basically something, that may occur on the right-hand side of the assignment operator. Contrary, a statement is some directive that doesn't produce directly a value.

For example, in Python, the ternary operator builds expressions, e.g.,

```
'odd' if x % 2 else 'even'
```

is an expression, so you can assign it to a variable, print, etc

While the following is a statement:

```
if x % 2:
   'odd'
else:
   'even'
```

It is not reduced to a value by Python, it couldn't be printed, assigned to a value, etc.

So far we were focusing more on the semantical differences between expressions and statements. But for a casual user, they are more noticeable on the syntactic level. I.e., there are places where a statement is expected and places where expressions are expected. For example, you can put a statement to the right of the assignment operator.

## OCaml/Reason/Haskell/F# story

In OCaml, Reason, and F# such constructs as `if`, `while`, `print` etc are expressions. They all evaluate to values and can occur on the right-hand side of the assignment operator. So it looks like that there is no distinction between statements and expressions. Indeed, there are no statements in OCaml grammar at all. I believe, that F# and Reason are also not using word statement to exclude confusion. However, there are syntactic forms that are not expressions, for example:

```
 open Core_kernel
```

it is not an expression, definitely, and

```
 type students = student list
```

is not an expression.

So what is that? In the OCaml parlance, they are called [definitions](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#definition), and they are syntactic constructs that can appear in the module on the, so called, top-level. For example, in OCaml, there are [value definitions](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#sec218), that look like this

```
 let harry = student "Harry"
 let larry = student "Larry"
 let group = [harry; larry]
```

Every line above is a definition. And every line contains an expression on the right-hand side of the `=` symbol. In OCaml there is also a `let` expression, that has form `let <v> = <exp> in <exp>` that should not be confused with the top-level `let` definition.

Roughly the same is true for F# and Reason. It is also true for Haskell, that has a [distinction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html) between expressions and declarations. It actually should be true to probably every real-world language (i.e., excluding brainfuck and other toy languages).

## Summary

So, all these languages have syntactic forms that are not expressions. They are not called statements per se, but we can treat them as statements. So there is a distinction between statements and expressions. The main difference from common imperative languages is that some well-known statements (e.g., `if`, `while`, `for`) are expressions in OCaml/F#/Reason/Haskell, and this is why people commonly say that there is no distinction between expressions and statements.